# My script returns an error when the test isn't corresponding to the Regex: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, regex, exception, python-2.x

My script down here is supposed to return a result in this format

```
[ {'heure':xxxx,'mid': xxxx,'type message': "e.g SMS.Message ", "Origine":xxx,"Destination":xxxx}]
```

Well it works but without the Type message I've just added this so I think that the regex isn't correct. :/ It also doesn't work when I add a data that doesn't have something that looks like the regex so I think I have to do a `try:` - `except:` but I don't know how. :/

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re 
################################_Function EXTRACT_############################################### 

def extraire(data):
    ms = re.match(r'(\S+).*mid:(\d+).*(R:NVS:\w+)', data) # heure & mid 
    k = re.findall(r"/\S+", data ) # source & destination extracte 
    return {'Heure':ms.group(1), 'mid':ms.group(2),'Type Message':ms.group(3),"Origine":k[0],"Destination":k[1]}


#################################################################################################

tableau = []  
data3 = "12:07:32.546 mta         Messages       I Doc O:TCARVAL (NVS:SMTP/jack.reacher@example.de) R:NVS:VOICE/+45154245 mid:6500"
data4 = "12:07:41.391 mta         Messages       I Rep O:TCARVAL (NVS:SMTP/brad.alison@yow.en) R:NVS:**SMS.Message**/+39872422 mid:6500"
data5 = "12:07:32.546 mta         Messages       I Doc O:TCARVAL (NVS:VOICE/+69517412carval@ifremer.no) R:NVS:SMS.Message/+34659879 mid:6500"
data6 = "12:07:32.545 mta     Messages   I Doc O:TCARVAL Example@whitout-slash.com        R:NVS:VOICE/01020150405 mid:9797"
data_list = [ data3, data4,data5, data6]
tableau = [extraire(data) for data in data_list]
print tableau
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your extraire function to this, as you are trying to access properties on `ms` even when
there are no matches. And when there are no matches, `ms` is None :

```
def extraire(data):
    ms = re.match(r'(\S+).*mid:(\d+).*(R:NVS:\w+)', data) # heure & mid                                 
    print(str(ms))
    if(ms is not None):
        k = re.findall(r"/\S+", data ) # source & destination extracte                                  
        return {'Heure':ms.group(1), 'mid':ms.group(2),'Type Message':ms.group(3),"Origine":k[0],"Desti\
nation":k[1]}
    else:
        return {}
```

Btw, your regex does not seem to match the text you intend to match.
You may get List index out of range error as well if  `k` does not contain the number of elements you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

"mid" is coming after "R:NVS" so your pattern has it in the wrong order

```
12:07:32.546 mta         Messages       I Doc O:TCARVAL (NVS:SMTP/jack.reacher@example.de) R:NVS:VOICE/+45154245 mid:6500
                                                                                           1                     2
```

So, you need to change the order in your pattern into something like this

```
(\S+).*(R:NVS:\w+).*mid:(\d+)
```

Btw. what do you `\S+` expect to match? Here it will match the first series of non whitespace characters in the string.